# Finding the closest spans id to replace the spans content

Tags: jquery, html

I'm provably over complicating this so stop me if I'm going down a rabbit hole. I'm trying to grab the id of a span when a checkbox is clicked and then change the content in that span.

I've tried a few things and I think I'm on the right track, but as I said I have a tendency to over complicate these things. By the way all the id's are different and being set by a database id number.

I've tried this

```
var readInput = $(".check span").attr('id');
$('#'.readInput).text('Read');
```

Which kind of sort of works. Except it only grabs the first id even if I am clicking on the third or forth checkbox....it also does not change the text.

I've also tried just grabbing the span and then id that way, but that was no way near what I need.

Any help would be wonderful!

the whole function looks like this... a lot of it is unnecessary for this problem though.

```
$('.memo input.checkIt').on("click", function(){
  var name_attr = $(this).attr('name');
  var hidden_input = $('input[name="' + name_attr + '"]');

  if($(this).siblings('a').attr("class") == 'checked') {
    hidden_input.val(0);
  }else {
    hidden_input.val(1);
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled').parent().addClass('disabled');

    var readInput = $(".check span").attr('id');
    $('#' + readInput).text('Read');

    console.log(readInput);
  }
});
```

and this is the html

```
<p class="pull-right check">
@if($cover_design_note->is_read)
    {{ date('m/d/Y g:i a', strtotime($cover_design_note->date)) }}&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="icon-thumbs-up program_this"></i> &nbsp; Read
  @else
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkIt" name="{{ $cover_design_note->id }}" /><span id="messRead{{ $cover_design_note->id }}"> Unread</span>
  @endif
</p>
```

Comment: Could you post the whole event handler and markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest(".check").find("span").text('Read');
```

Within the click handler `this` is the clicked element, then `.closest(".check")` gives you that element's containing `"check"` paragraph and then from there you can find the span.

You don't need to use the element's id at all, because although you can retrieve the id by the time you do so you must already have a reference to the right element so you can just set its `.text()` directly.

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much. I was originally trying to do something like this, but then decided to over complicate things...again!

Answer (score 1):

In javascript concatenation is done with a `+`:

Your selector should be:

```
$('#' + readInput).text('Read');
```

It may be easier to move to a class in the html for the `span` tag such as:

**HTML**

```
<div class="memo">
<p class="pull-right check">
&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="icon-thumbs-up program_this"></i> &nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkIt"/>
    <span id="somethingDynamic" class="messRead"> Unread</span>
</p> 
</div>
```

This would really boil down the javascript:

```
$('.memo input.checkIt').on("click", function(){
    //omitted other parts of code
    $('.messRead', $(this).parent()).text('Read');
 });
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.memo input.checkIt').on("click", function(){
    $('.messRead', $(this).parent()).text('Read');
 });
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/BYU3w/

Comment: Thank you, I'm used to php concatenation! I'm still having trouble getting the id though...